# Unexpected error in nested function

Tags: ocaml

Hey, Im pretty new to functional programming and am trying to write a function that gets a list as a input. This function should return the last element and the remaining list in a tuple.

```
let poplast l = let rec temp acc t = match t with
    |[] -> failwith "Error"
    |[x]-> (acc,x)
    |x::xs -> temp x::acc xs
    in temp [] l;;
```

This is the error I get is this:

Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'b * 'c

right after the third match. I really dont see whats wrong.

Comment: Becareful, your function actually returns the remaining list in reversed order. Maybe you could use List.rev

Answer (score 3):

OCaml parses `temp x::acc xs` as `(temp x) :: (acc xs)` but what you mean is `temp (x::acc) xs`.